# Please, explain to me the correct answer in the task

Tags: word-usage

> I'm  too busy today. I've got ____ things to do.
>
> - much
> - many
> - too many
> - too much

I had to choose from words much, many, too much, too many. Why isn't my answer correct? What was the right variant and why?

Comment: "Too many" is a good answer. You'll have to ask the people who created the test why they insist on only one of the possible answers.

Comment: Thanks! I asked my teacher and she agreed with me that this answer is correct. So the test will be modified

Comment: __Extra Information__: There is this idiom which summarizes the thought: [Too much on my plate](https://funkyenglish.com/idiom-much-plate/). So you can say: "There's too much on my plate today."

Answer (score 1):

For me it is a matter of style whether to write *many* or *too many* here. Neither alternative with *much* is right at all. In fact I would have said *I am too busy today, I have so many things to do* but your test does not even recognise that version. I suppose they do not like the repetition of *too* but that does not make the sentence wrong.

Comment: Thank you for this exhaustive answer! This answer will be counted as a correct

Comment: @Svinera - If you consider an answer to be correct, you should (a) up vote it and (b) click the tick mark. This will indicate to others that the question has been answered. I hope this helps!